# angular.module api in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`angular.module(name[, requires], configFn);`

---

Now I have two modules, and I can register them like below.

---

*in app.js*
angular.module('app',['parent-module'])

*in parent-module.js*
angular.module('parent-module',['sub-module'])

*in sub-module.js*
angular.module('sub-module',[])

---

Assume that I have four modules now, and If I register them in the same way:

---

*in app.js*
angular.module('app',['parent1-module','parent2-module'])

*in parent1-module.js*
angular.module('parent1-module',['sub-module'])

*in sub1-module.js*
angular.module('**sub-module**',[])

*in parent2-module.js*
angular.module('parent2-module',['sub-module'])

*in sub2-module.js*
angular.module('**sub-module**',[])

---

I will get errors because of the same sub-module registration in different js files.

---

If there are any methods which allow me to register the sub-modules with same names in different parent-modules?

Comment: this looks very over complicated, are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: @sableloki The app.js is in a Web Framework, the parentX-module.js/subX-module.js is developed by other teams, and the {0} in angular.module('app',[{0}]) is loaded from database. At first, we must assure that the parent module names in app is single, but if another team want to develop a sub-module with a name which is already existed in other parent module, how can I do it?

Comment: @HelpingHand Please see another comment reply.

Comment: Well then the module should be named with some namespace alias. As AngularJS itself does using `ng` prefix. Modules are independent and can only be identified using their names.

Comment: @Chandermani I know your meaning. The best practise of Angular.js is also suggest to do like this. But in this way, if there are many layers(such as sub-sub-modules), the module names will be longer and longer. So I want to know if there is a solution allow me to register module like fluent api: angular.module('parent-module',[]).module('sub-module',[]).